# Generating XML Request through xsd using generateDS

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xsd, python-generateds

I would like to
a) generate XML Requests
b) and Parse Responses

based on a schema(.xsd) i have from one of the OEM.

I researched on net and generateDS seemed to be the one i was looking for however i am struggling to make it work.

I was able to generate Python Classes however I am not sure if this is the right approach.

1. I am trying to generate xml requests in runtime using python modules created from XSD, is this approach correct for production applications.
   OR
   should i be generating xml requests through xml.etree.ElementTree (I do understand that in the background generateDS is also using that).
2. When i am instantiating a class it doesn't generate the complete xml output.

end result should be something like this:

````
<BroadsoftDocument protocol = "OCI" xmlns="C" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sessionId xmlns="">123123</sessionId>

    <command xsi:type="AuthenticationRequest" xmlns="">
        <userId>12431232131</userId>
    </command>
</BroadsoftDocument>```
  

Help on class AuthenticationRequest in module OCISchemaLogin_gds:

class AuthenticationRequest(OCIRequest)
 |  AuthenticationRequest(echo=None, userId=None, **kwargs_)
 |  
 |  AuthenticationRequest is 1st stage of the 2 stage OCI login process.
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      AuthenticationRequest
 |      OCIRequest
 |      OCICommand
 |      GeneratedsSuper
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, echo=None, userId=None, **kwargs_)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |
````

```
CODE:
auth_req = OCISchemaLogin_gds.AuthenticationRequest(userId = self.userId,)
command =[OCISchemaLogin_gds.OCICommand(extensiontype_='AuthenticationRequest') ]
message = OCISchemaLogin_gds.OCIMessage(protocol='OCI',sessionId=session, userId=self.userId, command= command)
message.export(sys.stdout,1)


OUTPUT:

    <OCIMessage  xmlns:None="C"  protocol="OCI">     <sessionId>12421321</sessionId>
        <userId>12321321</userId>
        <OCICommand xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="AuthenticationRequest"/>
    </OCIMessage>
SUCCESSFUL
```

am I even using it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

when you download genertaDS to your computer open tutorial/code/my_test.py get an example will build people.xml from people.xsd (xml schema).
by the way it also create people_api.py based on the schema with all the classes.

stages:
1. running from cmd:

```
python generateDS.py -o people.py people.xsd
```

this will creating people_api.py based on the schema with all the classes.
2. running from cmd:

```
python my_test.py
```

this will getting a xml output to stdout.